# Application or plugin for turning screenshots into searchable text?

Tags: windows, microsoft-outlook, search, ocr

It's a common practice in our company that people take screenshots of any software error situation they get into, and then they paste the screenshots in mail messages and/or Word documents that get sent and forwarded back and forth. I have lots of stuff like this in my Outlook mail archives, and the problem with it is, the screenshots aren't searchable, because they're just dumb images as far as Outlook or Windows Search are concerned. Sometimes I edit the original mail messages and type the text (typically an error message) from the screenshot into the message, but quite rarely, because it's slow and prone to typing errors.

Is there a program or Outlook or Windows plugin that would OCR and index images in the Outlook mail archives, so the image contents would become indexable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OneNote does this (as well as being useful in many other ways).

Comment: Thanks. I've never used OneNote, but it's available in our company's catalog/buffet of applications that can be ordered for install on workstations with a few mouseclicks. I'll check it out. (one of the nice sides of working in a large corporation)

Comment: Hopefully you'll find it as useful as I have; I try to replace most things I'd normally have jotted down on a notepad (besides drawings) and all those random text files / excel sheets with random info and tables.

Answer (score 0):

I used to use Evernote, which is capable of scanning text off of images.  I believe there is now an Outlook extension.

Comment: I suppose Evernote is a cloud service? No can do in our case.

Comment: Evernote is not a cloud service.

Comment: I stand corrected. :) I took a quick glance at their website and at first I thought you're required to upload everything to their service. I might try it for my personal use, but for work I'll try OneNote first because it's already available for me.

Comment: I also took another look at OneNote and it looks like it may have caught up with Evernote in terms of features.  But you are also restricted mostly to Microsoft.  Even though I hear there is an Ipad version.

Comment: @Ralph Winters - How is OneNote restricted to Microsoft?

Comment: @edusysadmin - I'm referring to the desktop version. No Mac or Linux support

Comment: @Raplh Winters - ahh, as in os restriction...when MS has the variety of products it does such a statement is a bit unclear.